# Rear brakes wear quickly - do I need redundant rear brakes?

Tags: brakes

On my bikes I find that I wear out the rear brake a lot faster than the front brake. In fact, I tend to avoid the front brake, and any time that I've used it exclusively, bad things would happen (like the rear of the bike flying over my head as I rush to get away from this flying heap of metal).

So I'm thinking... given that a disc brake system is just a pad that presses against the disc, has anyone considered attaching two completely independent sets of rear brakes to a single disc?

I suspect that one would need a single handle for activating both sets of rear brakes but I'm pretty sure it's not impossible. Apart from the obvious "your frame doesn't have mounts for two brake systems", are there any other reasons why this would be a bad idea? (Cost, weight etc. not being a factor.)

**Clarification**: my question is about the mounting of two sets of brake pads, specifically. I already know that two hydraulic lines can be merged (e.g., using [Outbraker](http://www.outbraker.com/)).

**Clarification 2**: just to reiterate (again), neither cost nor weight nor the complexity of the system are a factor *for me*, in other words I'm perfectly prepared to live with all of that, provided I get a more reliable, effective and powerful rear brake. The goal isn't just to reduce maintenance but to provide extra power to the rear brake.

**Update 3**: here's a photo

[image: dual rear calipers]

**Update 4**: I have accepted one of the answers below, but you should know that **I'm definitely doing it** -- going to install a second caliper on the rear brake, will probably also extend the size of the rear brake disc to the (rather expensive) [Hope 203 rotor](https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/brakes/hope-rohloff-specific-ventilated-floating-4-bolt-rotor-203-mm/?geoc=RU). Will post a picture and report when finished.

**Update 5:** someone might be reading this, so I wanted to give an update on something that I mentioned earlier - Outbraker, the two-hose variety. Basically this thing allows progressive braking with both calipers at the same time. I have installed it for a person who can only use the left hand for braking, and for that purpose it works rather well! The brake calipers no longer have a 'bite point' as the Outbraker acts like a time-delay mechanism.

**Update 6:** just wanted to post an update on the whole Outbraker thing. Long story short, v1 of Outbraker fell short of its described functionality -- it is actually pretty impossible to bleed, and it seemed to be losing air. Now, to be fair, Outbraker did send me v1.5 for free, but I haven't tested it, since changing brake lines is not a normal occurrence for me. So that's where we're at - nowhere. At least with Outbraker.

Comment: You should really consider using the front brake also. You’ll stop much faster.

Comment: The redundant system that backs up the rear brake is ... the front brake.

Comment: There are bicycles that only have one rear drum brake, i.e. in the hub. Those bicycles are for slower and steady commuters who do not bother with learning how to brake. The rest of us simply learned when and how to use front brakes. This is a skill no harder than learning to maintain balance on a bicycle and not fall on a side all the time.

Comment: Rear pads on my bikes wear out faster than front ones, even though I use both of them all the time. Why it is so is another question to ask, but it is definitely not caused only by avoiding the front brakes.

Comment: Learning the physics of the braking process is also liberating as knowledge scares away superstitions and urban legends.

Comment: I applaud the maker of Outbraker (linked item) for their contribution to natural selection. It couples the independent front and back brakes removing redundancy.  A failure (e.g. fluid leak) in the brake lever means no braking. I fail to see how it accounts for varying surface conditions, slope and rider weight distribute, so it will rarely achieve optimal braking (despite their claims).  I see it as being extremely beneficial in a few limited cases - e.g. one armed riders, but able bodied cyclists should learn to use brake - its not really that hard.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/46241/1116

Comment: I think you need to specify the goal (e.g., longer maintenance intervals) for this question to really take shape. As it stands it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @mattnz the discussion at hand isn't with Outbraker's ability to independently control both the front and rear brakes with the single lever; it is about using Outbraker to control *two rear calipers* that would be braking simultaneously

Comment: You may have already seen https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/34355/7309 but it's related. To give an indication of how little you can use your back brake: when commuting I rode for 3 days/50km a couple of months ago before realising that while the lever felt normal taking up the slack, I'd caught the rear v-brake noodle on a luggage rack and the left pad couldn't make contact with the rim. I only realised when I wanted to brake and signal (with my front brake hand) at the same time. This is by no means a on.

Comment: Not trying to disparage your riding, but it does sound like you need to work on your braking technique.  In short, you should be moving your body weight backward (bum off seat, straighten arms and legs and "moon" to your 6 o'clock).  The front brake should be on as hard as possible without breaking tyre traction AND without lifting the rear wheel. and the rear brake is there as a backup and helps to keep the bike going straight.  The rear brake only has whatever weight is on it while braking, so that's why you push your bodyweight backward.

Comment: @mattnz concur - outbreaker looks like a pressure-relief valve.  Which is good if you're a gas tank on fire, but not good in braking systems.

Comment: What are your riding conditions? Are we talking road? Downhill MTB? Different disciplines have different braking techniques, but none rely on using the back brake exclusively, and in general the harder you're pushing things, the more important it is to use the front brake and the more important it is to control your weight.

Comment: Could it be that your rear brake pads are softer and wearing faster, while the front pads are harder and living longer?  Hard pads last longer but brake worse, soft pads brake better but wear quicker.

Comment: This is interesting. I usually prefer braking with the front brake, unless there is reason to stop the bike asap, in which case I use both. The front brake brakes more before locking the wheel (because; physics) and it is easier to check visually the condition of the discs while riding. Red means bad. Consequently my front brakes wear at least twice as fast.

Comment: The rear brake will never be as efficient as you front brake. No matter how much power you put on. You rare tire simply will lock and slide, where as your front tire has much more friction when braking as your whole weight starts pressing it to the ground. Start learning how to use your front brake. Everything else doesn't really make a lot of sense. Btw. I love my front brake much more than with my rear brake. It's so much quicker.

Comment: @ChrisH this is inconsistent with the observation that the rear brake pads wear out much faster than front ones

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk did you read the question I linked? I should have taken a photo of my bike last night: the reflective sidewalls on the back are no longer reflective a week after a good wash; on the front they're bright. The same dirt coats the rims and wears  back rim brakes (disc brakes will be affected much less). *Your* rear brakes wear more because you use them too much and the front too little. My front (disc) pads on my tourer wear so much more than the back that I swapped them after 2500km.

Comment: Your photo looks like a twin pot caliper on the rear of a motorbike.  I'd suspect the front wheel has dual rotors with twin pots on each side, or quad pot calipers.

Comment: @Criggie yes, the screenshot is a motorcycle wheel. but I see no reason why one wouldn't do the same on a bike. after all, bikes also reach high speeds and need the stopping power

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk Bicycles lack in power, so weight is always an issue.  multiple calipers on a disk rotor will add nothing beyond excess weight.  The limiting factor on a disk rotor is heat, and by having more pads (or larger pads) you're increasing friction which is adding to heat.  The ONLY way this might be of any possible benefit is if you had two rotors, with a caliper on each one.  This would only work on the front wheel.  And any half-decent disk brake can already lock up the front wheel.  Why would you want to make this failure-mode even more accessible?

Comment: You need to learn to brake better - try watching some youtube clips.

Comment: Voting to leave open - its a bad idea and we shouldn't hide bad ideas with a delete.  Instead, the answers and votes should show the community's thoughts.

Comment: @Criggie still curious as to *why* it's a bad idea considering motorcycles do precisely this

Comment: Motorcycles do this because they are heavy and fast enough to heat the rear brake too. They also have lower center of gravity, so braking with rear wheel is not as bad as with bicycles.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk Motorbikes are _much_ heavier than bicycles and that weight is low down. That means that when you brake a motorbike, there's less tendency for the rear wheel to lift off the ground. Thus, motorbikes have more powerful rear brakes because, unlike a bicycle, they can use that power without skidding. (Motorbikes also have more powerful front brakes, because the extra weight and speed means they need more braking force.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby then the natural question is, what are the speed/weight criteria where this set-up would make sense? for example, would 30kg/30kph (electric bicycle) qualify?

Comment: The lightest motorbike (that is not a scooter or stepthrough) will have a wet-weight above 300+ kilos.

Comment: As with all this stuff, there's a fantastic sheldon brown article about using the front brake which will make you question your question. I followed Sheldon's guide and never looked back.

Comment: @Criggie 300kg? The motorbike I've dealt with the most (repair rather than riding) was a Honda H100A, which apparently [weighs 93kg](https://www.bikez.com/motorcycles/honda_h_100_s_1986.php).  That's old and very basic but even the [CBR125](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_CBR125R) is 137kg.  Even if that's dry weight, you'd have to include a fairly heavy rider to get to 300kg.

Comment: You've still got just as much heat to get ride of and you've reduced the rotor's ability to dissipate heat by covering it with a redundant set of calipers, even if you have independent hydraulics (two hands).

Comment: Also, what's that picture of a motorbike supposed to illustrate.  We've taken pains to point out how proper bikes are different to motorbikes

Comment: I'm late to the party but I'll add.  With the complexity and weight you add, you are better off just buying pads more often.  The better part of my riding time was on ice and snow, where rear braking is more appropriate and I also wear out my rear pads much faster.  However, being able to instantly lock the wheel doesn't increase braking performance.  Expensive brakes modulate better, which is what you actually want.  If your style is already rear brake heavy and you aren't going to change, your money is better spent on buying more pads.

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/27108/how-to-decelerate-effectively-with-a-rear-brake Also maybe appropriate to this situation.

Comment: @ChrisH dry weight is irrelevant, cos it is unrideable like that.  OK 300 kilos was a bit high but its still going to be 15x or 20x what a heavy bicycle weighs, leaving the powered bike to be a substantial fraction of the total.

Comment: @Criggie, yes, I saw a figure saying wet adds 30kg to a small bike, i.e. just the fuel, battery and oil for a motorbike weighs as much as a heavy e-bike. I'm tempted to argue down to about 6-8x but your conclusion is sound so I won't cherry-pick examples . I like to think of it as *a motorbike weighs more than its rider, a bike less* because that says something really simple about weight distribution.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk thank you for coming back and adding progress.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk its been two years since the last update - were there any further developments?

Comment: @Criggie added a small update

Comment: This question has gathered the wrong answers because it was posted on the wrong site. This site is about human-powered bikes, not about motorcycles. Pity nobody realized when the question was posted.

Comment: @shox please don't edit the question info a different one, even if it is obvious that the original is asking for wrong thing.

Comment: @ojs whoever moderated my change agreed. Stack exchange is about having useful questions and answers. The title didn't match the body of the question, I simply edited the title to match what is asked in the body making more useful long term. If you disagree feel free to change it back.

Comment: @shox I saw the moderation decision, and I can assure that the person has long history of not reading the question he is answering to or editing. I really don't care for edit war.

Comment: @ojs, sorry I don't think I follow. In anycase the comment section is not the correct place to discuss meta aspects of a question. I didn't edit the question, only the title. The original title was simply the OP suggesting a solution which didn't sum up the actual body of the question. The answers provide advice on increasing braking power, technique etc. OP is suggesting redundant brakes as a solution to a wear issue but asking how to fix the wear issue. Again feel free to revert the edit, I won't fight it.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The system you suggest has no benefit. The effectiveness of the rear brake is limited by the fact that braking moves your weight forwards and off the rear wheel. The brake you already have should already be capable of skidding your rear wheel. This tells you that the limiting factor isn't the power of the rear brake, but the grip of the rear tyre. Making the rear brake more powerful won't make you stop faster: it just makes you skid sooner. And bear in mind that skidding is not the fastest way to stop – that (and keeping control) is why cars have anti-lock brakes.

Instead, you need to practise using the brakes properly. If pulling the front brake sends you over the handlebars, you're pulling it too hard. Brakes are not binary: they're not just "on" or "off". Learn how much front brake you can use without endangering yourself (practise on a quiet street at gradually increasing speeds) and remember to brace against the handlebars as you brake so your weight doesn't flop forwards.

Comment: Good explanation of the physics of the process. It is worth underlining the final point of this reasoning once again: once your wheel is blocked and skids, the braking force has reached its limit and will not increase no matter how hard you continue pressing the brake lever. Another point, less obvious for those who missed their physics classes, is that "rolling" wheel friction is higher then skidding friction . Thus, it is counterproductive to block wheels. That is why cars have ABS systems

Comment: Skidding may be the fastest *available* way to stop if you don't have antilock brakes that can pulsate the brakes many  times a second while sensing the onset of lockup to prevent it.

Comment: @Kaz I don’t think so. In the days before ABS was common, the advice was to let off the brakes and reapply them, repeatedly if necessary. ABS modulates very quickly, which allows you to stay right on the edge of the skid, getting maximum braking. Without ABS, you’re not going to be right on the edge but you should still be able to get more braking than a skid. Skids don’t brake you very hard because, as Grigory points out, static friction (the contact point of a rolling tyre isn’t moving with respect to the ground) is significantly higher than dynamic friction (tyre skidding across the ground)

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov the main reason cars have ABS is that blocked wheels don't have any _direction_ authority. In particular, blocking the rear wheels in a car leads to oversteer/spin-out, whereas blocking the front wheels eliminates all steering. On a bike, blocking the rear wheel isn't that bad (you can still stabilise with weight distribution) but blocking the front wheel is almost sure to lose balance. — You're right that, at least on dry and solid ground, the contact friction of a rolling wheel is also higher than the skidding friction of a blocked one, but the difference isn't that big.

Comment: By the way, folks, a wheel that’s not rotating because the brakes have been applied too hard is “locked”, not “blocked”.

Comment: @DavidRicherby *the advice was to let off the brakes and reapply them, repeatedly if necessary* How many times can you do this in some emergency situation which lasts all of two seconds?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, in my comment I did not touch the topic of control loss, which is indeed more important on any vehicle than braking (it is wiser to steer away and avoid trouble compared with just stopping before it). And yes, the friction difference is not that big but still motivates me to avoid skidding with any wheel. I've actually read about some types of ABS-systems for bicycles, meant to be installed on a fleet of city bikes which are used by people of varying skill.

Comment: @Kaz to clarify David's point, that was about cars, which take rather more than 2 seconds to stop if they start skidding (2 seconds is a reasonable approximation at a range of realistic speeds on a dry road, when skidding isn't all that likely)

Comment: @Kaz http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/211_fall2002.web.dir/ben_townsend/staticandkineticfriction.htm This site has tables with static and kinetic friction coefficients for tires+asphalt. They show that if you are even moderately competent modulating your brakes, you are much better off not skidding, the difference between static and kinetic friction is so large.

Answer (score 11):

There are 4-piston disc brakes for bicycles that in a sense accomplish the same thing. Some have had 4 pads and others just 2 really big ones. The rotor's ability to manage heat is a bottleneck to the whole concept. You can of course get a bigger rotor, but at that point you're doing a lot of work to mitigate being nervous about the front brake, which leads to the next issue here.

The rear brake or brakes have slowed down the bike as much as they're going to once they lock the wheel. Getting that level of braking power in sufficiently demanding conditions isn't just a given, like how for example it sometimes might require a brake like the aforementioned 4-piston downhill/freeride brakes, but it's generally pretty attainable with existing designs.

Most cyclists who have been doing it for a while get pretty strongly opinionated against any brake system that downplays the front brake. The reason is that physics dictate that for the bike to stop as fast as possible, you need to stop the front wheel. It's best to develop mastery with the front brake, because you need it for emergency stops.

Comment: I already have quad-piston disc brakes on a 180mm rotor. It's not so much me being nervous about the front brake but rather ensuring that if I use the rear brake I get the same efficiency *as if* I was using both front and rear.

Comment: The physics of braking is so that the more the rear brake is efficient, the less "weight" comes to the rear wheel. Less weight means skidding starts earlier, which means the rear braking force limit is reached earlier. To keep rear axle weight high you will need to move the center of gravity closer to it, ideally behind it, to reverse the effect. But that is essentially turning the rear wheel into a front wheel!

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk It's physically impossible to stop a bike using only the rear brake in less time than it would take using both. You simply do not have the same efficiency when using only the rear brake. You *will* stop faster if you use the front brake too.

Comment: During my MC licence course I learned that ~90% of the braking power comes from the front wheel/brakes, this is because the weight is shifted towards the front when you brake. So it is a good idea to learn to primarily use the front brakes whenever possible. And yes, this applies to bicycles as well.

Comment: A completely different tip I learned, is the concept is [countersteering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countersteering). An absolutely critical knowledge when riding a MC. Though many bicycle riders do this as well without realising it, you can greatly improve  yours skills by being aware and actively taking advantage of it.

Comment: @David I daresay _all_ cyclists use countersteering. But you're right that most aren't aware of it and it _would_ be useful for them to learn about it. — That 90% figure seems a bit questionable to me here, at that point you're already very close to a stoppie. Most cyclists would have already gone over the handlebars before that happens. But, significantly more than 50% it is, as everybody already said.

Comment: @David that may be the case, but breaking with the front brake *exclusively* and without ABS is not feasible on a bike

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk You're wrong for most riding. On surfaced roads, even in the wet, you don't really need a back brake (you might need to plan for not braking on bends, but that's a good idea anyway).  On dirt tracks, the same applies. Of course it's a bit different on MTBs, but you haven't clarified what type of riding you're doing (not that it changes the conclusion: learn to use your front brake)

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk Are you talking about mountain biking? Because on a flat surface it's **easy** to ride without a rear brake.

Comment: @WillVousden that's provided you brake gently. if you break abruptly, particularly at high speed, the rear wheel will fly over you

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk If you go over the front wheel, you're not using your brakes properly. I've ridden over 100,000km since I started cycling, and have never once gone over the front wheel. And that includes plenty of high-speed emergency stops.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk The physics of this have been explained already, but perhaps look at the front brakes of a performance motorbike next time you see one. You'll notice that the front disks are **considerably** bigger, and they often have  two of them.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to have a redundant rear brake is to have a rear coaster brake with a rim brake or disk brake.

One could argue that fixies with rear rim brakes are doubly redundant.

Of course as David Richerby is pointing out, the **real** problem is your lack of front brake control, not with your rear brakes.

Comment: Or rim + disc, but your solution means no need to mount a second lever. Of course a lot of fixies with rim brakes were designed to have flip-flop hubs with a freewheel on one side, at which point the rear brake is a necessity.

Comment: Plus-sized rims on bikes typically do not support rim brakes. But it's an interesting idea!

Comment: Huh?? You’re thinking caliper brakes. Plenty of V brakes support plus size rims.

Comment: @RoboKaren Plus-sized rims typically do not have an edge that is suitable for either conventional rim brakes or V brakes because there is no surface area to break against - they are flush with the wheel. They are typically marked as *disc brake only*.

Answer (score 6):

Focusing on the question of adding two brake systems to the same wheel:

I had a tandem that had three brakes - front and rear hydraulic rim brakes and a hub-mounted cable-operated drum brake which was for limiting maximum speed on a downhill.

The drum brake was set with a barend shifter, and was very much Set and Forget for the descent.  This is quite common with touring tandems, and rare but not impossible on a touring single bike.

---

There is nothing stopping you fitting Rim and Disk brakes to a bike, as long as it has proper stops on the frame. Bolt-on disk brake mounts are useless hacks so avoid them.

Some bikes have caliper, canti and disk mounts on forks and/or stays, so you could have up to six separate wheel brakes, plus a coaster in the rear or drum/roller brake on the front and rear.  However some riders would call this a mild case of overkill.

Your main problem with anything above 2 brakes is control.  You only have two hands, and trying to run two brakes with one hand is going to give extra cognitve load in an emergency.  Partial workaround could be two hand brakes and a pedal brake.

---

Side note:, you have another speed reducing system which is your posture.  If you're descending too fast, you can sit up and catch some wind with your torso, and splay your legs to catch wind with your legs.  Being less aero will reduce your top speed to something less exciting and more manageable.  Not a braking system as such, but a valid technique anyway.

---

Stern note:  That outbraker thing sounds like it should slot in for **your** specific use, but its marketed as a way to control two separate brakes from one lever.   In some jurisdictions, a road vehicle is legally required to have two discreet and unrelated braking systems, so separate front and rear brakes with no common components.

Upshot, the outbreaker would be illegal in New Zealand as their website describes it, unless the bike also has a coaster brake or a second brake on the other hand functioning separately.   Someone who needs that functionality to work around a disability would be well-advised to get approval in writing, to guard against legal liability issues if they were involved in an accident that could be blamed on braking somehow.  Insurers are weasels and would totally do that.

Comment: There is no issue with control in the set-up I describe, though. For example, you can have Front+Rear1 on one handle amd Rear2 on another.

Comment: A half-unzipped jacket is a very effective air-brake for sustained descents.  Not only does it pretty much double the width of your torso, it approximates a parachute in shape and therefore drag coefficient.  Just be sure to zip it up again before you start pedalling

Comment: @ChrisH also great for hypothermia and potential pneumonia, I imagine

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk that depends on your conditions. *Jacket* in this context often refers to a thin rain jacket, as worn when layering, so while it keeps the wind off it doesn't provide much insulation (and we often get intermittent rain) here so end up with the jacket on and a bit warm.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk depends on your location, elevation, and weather.  Simply sitting up and making yourself less aero to catch more wind was the side-note.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk Pneumonia is a bacterial infection. Unzipping your jacket doesn't cause bacterial infections.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Pneumonia, as many other diseases, is often caused by bacteria and viruses already present in the organism or common in the crowded environment. whether you get ill depends on your immunity and how the immunity is compromised, for example by hypothermia. For common cold it happens by limiting the blood flow in the nose. Those dismissing any temperature effects and ridiculing others by saying "diseases are cause by bacteria and viruses, not temperature" are way oversimplifying the problem. No-one thinks that diseases are caused by temperature instead of viruses and bacteria.

Answer (score 4):

Some tandems are set up with two sets of rim brake pads, so that both riders can brake independently.  But the limiting factor here is heat dissipation -- both rims and disks can heat up with prolonged braking to the point where braking effectiveness is compromised, and doubling up on the pads only speeds this process.

If you want maximal braking while minimizing the over-the-top risks of the front brake, and complexity is not an issue for you, consider the scheme I've suggested before:  A front brake which is activated by the rear one.

Basically, the rear caliper would be on a lever, so that, when activated, it would rotate with the wheel for a few inches.  This motion of the rear caliper would then be transferred to the front brakes to activate them.

So the front brakes would only be activated when the rear wheel has traction.  If the front brake is too strong and the rear wheel begins to lift, then its traction is lost and the front brake is released.  A sort anti-lock brake system.

Comment: Interestingly, ABS is a system that's been made real by Bosch for ebikes: https://www.bosch-ebike.com/en/products/abs/

Comment: You just reinvented SureStop :) https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/46241/how-does-the-surestop-braking-system-work

Comment: I’ve seen tandems with disk brakes and an additional rim brake on the rear wheel for the second rider.

Comment: @Michael I'm no expert on tandems, but I wonder if the second rear brake is operated by the stoker to avoid the captain having too many brake levers, while existing mainly to avoid overheating a single braking system on long descents.  Rather like Criggie's answer

Comment: @ChrisH: Yes, that appears to be the case. Maybe it’s also for psychological reasons so that the stoker at least has some control over the vehicle ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your initial issue you state is that your rear brake pads wear out "too quickly".

With bikes there is no hard and fast rule as to which should wear out first. In a car the weight of the occupants has little or no bearing on how the brakes wear. The vehicle weight will shift as it will while breaking as the occupants are a small amount of the total weight and can't do much to change how that weight shift will occur.

On a bike you choose how to apply the brakes (biasing front or rear as you will, in your case rear) and you control your body which weighs significantly more than the bike. Anyone who has ridden significant rock faces can attest that body position will greatly affect your braking performance and can be the difference between having traction or locking up a specific brake.

If (as originally stated) your issue is brake pad life (not stopping power) then you don't have a problem. Replace the pads as needed. I go through rear tires much quicker than front. Do I switch to a tougher compound? No. What I care about is traction. If that means buying new rear tires more often, so be it. It's a wear item and I need to replace it as I wear it out.

If braking power is the issue (which is stated later as a goal) then step 1 is rotor size. I had a hardtail with 180mm front and 160mm rear. With my braking technique at the time I found the rear brake did not have enough power. I increased the rear rotor to 180mm and it suited my style perfectly. Inexpensive and just what I was seeking.

On my latest bike I had 180f/180r. I found the front braking power and bite to be not quite what I needed/wanted. I increased the front rotor to 200mm and it's perfect for me.

If rotors don't provide sufficient stopping power it's time to look at pad compounds then brakes (lever/caliper). A 4 piston caliper is going to give more power than a 2, but it varies on brand and model. The brake brand and model used isn't stated so it's difficult to provide advice. If you are running something like Code, Saint or MT7 brakes and don't have enough power with big rotors I'd hazard technique is at issue. No racers to my knowledge run dual calipers. I won't call them redundant since with a shared hydraulic line they are not redundant. If one fails they both fail.

Brake pads are cheap. If that's your issue, but them in bulk to save on shipping (and learn to replace them yourself if you aren't already capable.. it's easy). If power is the issue, buy a better rear brake (for MTB something like SRAM Code, Shimano SAINT, Magura MT7 etc). You don't have to run matching brakes front and rear, so upgrading one isn't a big deal. Most people want the same feel front and rear, but it sounds like you aren't getting what you want out of one end, so changing just one might be the solution.